# Create a dynamic SQL Insert from array object

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I have a project in Typescript where I need to create an Insert with all the elements of the object to make only one Insert, instead of one Insert for each array.

This is my current function:

```
public async insert() {

        let object = [{ cod: 'CO',
        file: 'CO_SER.csv',
        exists: 1},
      { cod: 'ES',
        file: 'ES_INS.csv',
        exists: 1 } ];


        for (let elem of object) {
            let insert = `INSERT INTO databaseID VALUES ("${elem.cod}", "${elem.file}", ${elem.exists})`;
        }

    }
```

This is what I get:

```
INSERT INTO databaseID VALUES ("CO", "CO_SER.csv", 1)
INSERT INTO databaseID VALUES ("ES", "ES_INS.csv", 1)
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
INSERT INTO databaseID VALUES ("CO", "CO_SER.csv", 1), ("ES", "ES_INS.csv", 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let object = [
  { cod: 'CO',
    file: 'CO_SER.csv',
    exists: 1},
  { cod: 'ES',
    file: 'ES_INS.csv',
    exists: 1 } ];

let insert = `INSERT INTO databaseID VALUES ` + 
  object.map(
    elem => `("${elem.cod}", "${elem.file}", ${elem.exists})`
  ).join(', ')

console.log(insert)
```